# Is it possible to manipulate the format on a DataGridView that is bound to a Data Source?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, datagridview

*I´m using SQL Server 2005 and Visual Studio 2008, C#.*

In the data source (the SQL Server data table) I use the date format **mm/dd/yyyy**, however, in a forms overview (DataGridView) users would like to see a completely other format, with year, week number and day number of week (**yyww,d**).
I´ve created an algorithm for this transformation, but can I populate the affected cells with yyww,d instead of mm/dd/yyyy?
And in that case - how would I do it?

I guess I need to do it after the cells are populated, but before they are shown.

The generic question is - how do I manipulate the format of Data Source bound DataGridView cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CellFormatting Event can help it... it is triggered after populating data to cell and u can format that data as per requirement in that event