# How do I manipulate the format on a DataGridView that is bound to a Data Source?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, datagridview

*I´m using SQL Server 2005 and Visual Studio 2008, C#.*

In the data source (the SQL Server data table) I use the **DateTime** format **mm/dd/yyyy**, however, in a forms overview (DataGridView) users would like to see a completely other format, with year, week number and day number of week (**yyww,d**) which is in **string** format.
I´ve created an algorithm for the transformation between values (date to weekday), but can I populate the affected cells with yyww,d (string) instead of mm/dd/yyyy (DateTime)?

This is what I´ve been testing out, without success
(and note, it´s on the last line the problem becomes obvious, as the cell value won´t accept a **string** on runtime - it still wants to be a **DateTime**...)

```
  private void DataGridViewQueryFindRequests_CellFormatting(
     object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
  {
     string weekAndDay = "";

     DataGridViewCell cell = 
         DataGridViewQueryFindRequests.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];


     if (cell.ColumnIndex == 13 && cell.Value == null)
        mEmptyRow = true;

     if ((cell.ColumnIndex == 14 || cell.ColumnIndex == 15) && !mEmptyRow)
     {
        weekAndDay = ClassWeeksAndDates.dateToWeekNumber(Convert.ToDateTime(cell.Value));

        cell.ValueType = typeof(string);

        cell.Value = weekAndDay;
     }
   }
```

Comment: Hi, is this question different from this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051192/is-it-possible-to-manipulate-the-format-on-a-datagridview-that-is-bound-to-a-data are you still looking for an answer here?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem just few days ago.

Try to not change the `ValueType` in `CellFormatting` event but only the `Value`.

To avoid receiving a `FormatException` then at runtime, you have to convert/parse the value when you want to store it back

You can to this in the `CellParsing` event and you can convert here your desidered visible format **yyww,d** to the accepted DateTime format **mm/dd/yyyy**

Maybe look at this answer could help: [DataGridView Cell Editing issue with decimal/hexadecimal formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054767/datagridview-cell-editing-issue-with-decimal-hexadecimal-formatting/3062534#3062534)